# Using collectable items to change a gameobject Unity

Tags: c#, unity, 2d, platform

I’ve been working on a 2D platform side scroller. I’m rather new to Unity and C#.
Basically what I’ve achieved so far is a character which can collect Logs throughout the game and those logs are stored in an inventory (a simple count variable). Those logs can then be used to increase the values of Campfires. This is where the problem starts, I’m trying to figure out how to check the currentValue of the campfire and show a different sprite animation of the fire. (As shown below)

**In short:**

> Player gathers log (count += 1) -> if ( count > 0 && Player collides
>   with (or in range of) Campfire && presses E -> Player is able to use
>   log  { call throw_log_animation; count -= 1; currentValue +=25%; call
>   new fireAnimation; }
>
> if Fire = 100% -> Player CANNOT use log. If Fire = 0% -> Game Over.

[image]

Collectable items code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CollectableItems : MonoBehaviour {

    private int count;
    public GUIText countText;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        count = 0;
        setCountText ();
    }

    // OnTriggerEnter 2D
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        // If gameObject comes in contact with player
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "WoodStumps") {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            count += 1;
            setCountText ();
        }

        // If player comes in contact with gameObject
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "CampFire") {
            if (count > 0) count -= 1; 
            else gameObject.SendMessage("No logs");

            setCountText ();
        }

    }


    void setCountText() {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    }
}
```

If anything is unclear, don’t hesitate to ask. I’m looking forward to your solutions and idea’s!

Comment: You might want to create a CampFire script that controls the state of it that way you can check its intensity prior to adding the logs to the fire

Answer (score 1):

You've already got most of the setup. What you could do is just control the Campfire from the other collider inside the Collision method [untested code] :

```
// in CollectableItems.cs
    //...
       if (other.gameObject.tag == "CampFire") {
            if (count > 0) {
                var campfire = other.gameObject.GetComponent<CampFireController>();
                if(campfire.TryAddLog()) {
                    // remove log
                    count -= 1;
                    // increase character warmth variables etc
                }
            else {
                gameObject.SendMessage("No logs");
            }

            setCountText ();
        }
    //...

// in CampFireController.cs
public class CampFireController : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool HasFuel { get { return fuelCount > 0; } }
    public bool IsFull { get { return fuelCount >= fuelMax; } }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return fuelCount == 0; } }

    private int fuelCount = 0f;
    private int fuelMax = 4f;

    void Start() {
        // assume 1 log from the player is consumed when creating a camp fire
        fuelCount = 0f;

        // try and burn fuel every 10 seconds
        InvokeRepeating("BurnFuel", 10f, 10f);
    }

    void Update() {

    }

    public bool TryAddLog() {
        if(! IsFull) {
            fuelCount ++;
            // change sprite fire size; increase
            return true; // we managed to add a log to the camp fire
        }
        return false; // couldn't add a log as we're full so fail out
    }

    private void BurnFuel() {
        if(HasFuel) {
            fuelCount --;
            // change sprite fire size; decrease
        } else if(IsEmpty) {
            // change sprite to no flames i.e. gone out
        }
    }
}
```